# WSGI запуск на под домене

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, wsgi

У меня есть приложения Flask, как мне запустить его на поддомене? Если я запускаю pod.domen.ru то сайт работает на pod.domen.ru и domen.ru, а мне надо только на pod.domen.ru

Comment: WSGI здесь абсолютно ни при чём, всё зависит от настроек используемого вами веб-сервера

Answer (score 0):

Перед WSGI сервером можно поставить проксирующий сервер на NginX с конфигом вроде такого:

```
upstream app1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
upstream app2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen  *:80;
    server_name  domen.ru;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  app1;
    }
}

server {
    listen  *:80;
    server_name  pod.domen.ru;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  app2;
    }
}
```

Это позволит настроить различные обработчики и прочие правила для разных серверов.

Изучение начать можно отсюда:

- [uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io: Nginx support for uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html)
- [webdevblog.ru: Развертывание приложения на Django с uWSGI и nginx](https://webdevblog.ru/razvertyvanie-prilozheniya-na-django-s-uwsgi-i-nginx-v-proizvodstvennoj-srede/)

Comment: я совсем не разбираюсь в этом, может есть готовое решение?
VDS - ubuntu.
Библиотека которую я использую - gevent ( gevent.pywsgi ).
Так же использую flask.

Comment: @Mr.ribi А какая задача-то? Обрабатывать несколько доменов одним сервером или обрабатывать запросы по одному домену кидая ошибку на другие? Если первое, то вы, сударь, обленились!  Решение простейшее, NginX ставится и в таком простом сценарии настраивается за 10 минут, при этом NginX является промышленным стандартом и даёт богатый арсенал функционала.

Comment: Обрабатывать скриптом поддомен, а не домен ( как это делается ), повторюсь, при запуске приложения в питоне с поддоменом, то всё другие поддомены начинают работать, как и основной домен, а мне надо именно обрабатывать поддомен

Comment: @Mr.ribi А всё потому, что программы слушают не домены, а порты. Вы не сможете запустить несколько серверов-скриптов на одной машине, чтобы все слышали порт 80 по одному и тому же IP-адресу, это физически так не работает, т.к домен не существует в терминологии TCP/IP. Поэтому настраивается прокси-сервер, который принимает все входящие запросы, и уже потом, в зависимости от домена, пробрасывает их нужным программам-обработчикам, по локалхосту и уникальному порту или по сокету. Повторюсь: используйте NginX. Либо просто удалите пересылку прочих доменов на этот сервер 